# My custom "distance_of_time_in_words"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I create my own version of "distance_of_time_in_words"? For example I want it to say "today, yestarday, the other day, 5 days ago, last Week... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the implementation of distance_of_time_in_words in the Rails codebase, that will be a good place to start.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb

Comment: Thanks. This is very advanced for me though. I hoped for a plugin but it seems there isn't one.

Comment: you just need to create a helper file (in your helpers directory) that implements it how you want that you will then wrap your date in to give you the output you want.